# Mysql - How to alias a whole table data in a left join

Tags: mysql, sql, alias, foreign-key-relationship

Suppose I have two tables,
`users(id, name, gender)`
`posts(id, user_id(foreign_key from users), body, date)`

I need to query a post and result should be like below

```
[
  "id": 1,
  "body": "Some post body",
  "date": "24-10-2015"
  "user": [
   "id": 23,
   "name": "FirstName LastName",
   "gender": "male"
  ]
 ]
```

I tried this, its giving all attributes from both the tables. But I need attributes from `users` table as an array. How can I do that?

```
SELECT * 
  FROM  `posts` 
  LEFT 
  JOIN  `users` 
  ON  `posts`.`user_id` =  `users`.`id`
```

Comment: `But I need attributes from users table as an array` . Can you give some sample data and desired output?

Comment: I have mentioned desired output already and given the tables structure too. What else you required?

Comment: you mean you literally need data enclosed in `[` `]` with each result in a new line?

Comment: A result set without a data set. Unfortunately SO decorum prohibits me from saying what I think about that.

Comment: I need data enclosed in `[ ]` from a table that is referenced with foreign-key.

Comment: check the answer I gave now and let us know if you have any issues

Comment: Thanks, I was checking for the same. But how about performance? Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried this. 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a907b/21

You can format further.

```
SELECT CONCAT('[\n "id": ',POSTS.ID,', \n "body": "'
  ,BODY,'",\n  "date": "' ,DATE,'"\n  "user": [\n   "id": '
  ,USERS.ID,',\n   "name": "', NAME,'",\n   "gender": "'
  ,gender,'"\n  ]\n ]')
FROM USERS
LEFT JOIN POSTS ON users.id=posts.user_id
```

To view in sqlfiddle, use the dropdown on `Run SQL` button and choose `plaintext output`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group_concat` function. This function generate user data in comma separated form. I haven't much idea of your database tables but i am try to set an ex-

```
SELECT post.Id, group_concat(users.id) as user_id, group_concat(users.name) as user_name, group_concat(users.gender) as user_genders
FROM  `posts` 
LEFT  JOIN  `users` 
ON  `posts`.`user_id` =  `users`.`id` 
GROUP BY posts.id
```